# Join objects which using the same material

Tags: mesh

I have 117 objects and I tried to connect them into one object and separate by material, but it didn't worked because blender separates the objects which have duplicated materials too (material.001, material.002 etc.). How can I join these objects ?

Comment: Could You clarify the question a bit? What exactly do You want to achieve? One mesh containing 117 objects, and every one of them must have different material or one mesh with single material or something else?

Comment: Hi Mzidare, some of my objects are using the same material, I just want to connect them, but how ?  ( I can do this manually but it will take a lot of time because I have 117 objects)

Comment: If You wanna to connect all objects using the same material, go to Select>Linked>Material. This way You will select all objects sharing the same material. Then CTRL+J to join them.

Comment: But when I click on the "Select>Linked>Material" it will not select them because of the annoying .000 thing on every material.

Comment: Ok, so we're clear on that. It's not the same material, but different materials with the same settings. Then maybe those objects have similar names, different then other objects. If so, deselect all, go to Select>Select Pattern, then write shared part of the name before * and uncheck Extend. Then press ENTER

Comment: No, they haven't, each object has different name. Any solution ?  Maybe select objects which using the same texture ? Thank you that you trying to help anyway.

Comment: Sure. If they have the same texture, then select one of them and go to Select>Linked>Texture

Comment: Doesn't working, because blender puts .001 to the same textures too -.- "col_dirt.jpg.001" this is very annoying

Comment: Help me somebody please !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fear not my friend. Here I come with help for You :) You have to open text editor in Blender, click New to create new text file, and paste this code snippet (below), then change "somename" to the materials name before .001 (f.ex. if it's Material, Material.001 and so on, You have to write Material there). Then press Run Script and watch the magic (it should select all objects having material with this name part).Important is to keep indentations cause Python is very sensitive about it, so in line 1 and 2 there is no indentation line 3 - 4 spaces, line 5 - 8 spaces, line 6 - 12 spaces.

`import bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene
for ob in scene.objects:
    for slot in ob.material_slots:
        if ("somename" in slot.name):
            ob.select = True`